# Accessing VisualSVN from external web server (DMZ)

Tags: iis, svn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

We have an VisualSVN Server running on our development server. An external vendor needs to access / use it (primary via TortoiseSVN, sometimes by using the web interface).

Since our IT does not allow external access to internal servers, they need to use a webserver in the DMZ (Demilitarized Zone).

Is there a way to redirect the external SVN access from this DMZ-webserver to the internal development server (preferable by using IIS 7 on the DMZ server)

Comment: What are your requirements for DMZ server? Have you considered deploying another VisualSVN Server instance on DMZ with slave repositories? See https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/multisite-replication/

Comment: thanks for the hint, I'll have a look onto it (even if a cost free solution would be better :-))